# Group objects with iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, grouping

In my iPhone app, I have a number of `UIImageView` that do the same thing, then a second load which do the same thing. Can I some how tag/group these so that I can simply reference all the objects with one name? Otherwise it means having to have dozens of lines of code for a single repetitive action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place all the `UIImageView`s in one super `UIView`. Depending on what you want to do, you could for example easily hide all objects inside the `UIView` with one line of code.

Comment: Well say I have these UIImageViews: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 and 2-1, 2-2 and 2-3. I need to check to see if any from group one have collied with any from group two. But it takes many repetitive lines to check this, which is why I would like to find a way of using one universal name for each group.

Comment: How about two arrays of UIImageViews and two loops?